# forcing json_encode to encode (sparse) array as indexed array in php

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to transfer an array between the host and my webpage using JSON. On the host, I have a php script which reads a number of rows from a mysql table and creates an array out of it.

```
$query="select ID,val,size from db;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $idx= (int) $row['ID'];
  $data[$idx]['val']=$row['val'];
  $data[$idx]['size']=$row['size'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Normally, the ID's are incremented linearly between, for example, 0 and 99.. In this case, the json_encoded output is an array (and will be interpreted as an array in javascript... If I do an array.length, I get 100 as the answer)....
   Sometimes, a few of the rows are missing from the table (maybe there was no row with an idx=40)... In this case, the array is json_encoded as a collection of objects. In javascript, if I try to look at array.length, I get an undefined result. I'd like to force the data array to be interpreted as an indexed array with null/0 values for missing rows. Is there an easy way to do this? It looks like the json_encode function has an option to force encoding as an associative array, but not the other way around.

Thx.

Comment: Just curious, but what do you need the length for? Can't you just set a length property in the array like `$data['length']=count($data)`? If you need the length for looping over the data, gaps in the numbers will mess it up/report incorrect length values. You can use a `for in` loop (similar to a php foreach).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="select ID,val,size from db;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$maxId = -1;
$defaultValue = null;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $idx= (int) $row['ID'];
   if($maxId < $idx)
       $maxId = $idx;
   $data[$idx]['val']=$row['val'];
   $data[$idx]['size']=$row['size'];
}
for($i=0;$i<$maxId;$i++)
    if(!isset($data[$i))
        $data[$i] = $defaultValue;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: One of the things that I had noticed was that if the rows were returned from the mysql database out of order (ie, idx=1 came out first followed by idx=0), then even if it was a full array, it would be encoded as a collection of objects, and not as an array... Allocating & initializing the array ahead of time seemed to work well.

Answer (score 1):

I would define $data as a full array and then replace elements inside of it.

```
$data = array_fill($starting_index, 100, null);

$query="select ID,val,size from db;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $idx= (int) $row['ID'];
  $data[$idx]['val']=$row['val'];
  $data[$idx]['size']=$row['size'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, but that's Javascript for you. I usually work around this by adding another level to my data structure:

```
$data['size'] = count($myarray);
$data['array'] = $myarray;

echo json_encode($data);
```

That way you get the length included for "free", without having to do any client-side looping/counting.